# How can I install a previous version of xserver-xorg-video-intel?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, downgrade

I am suffering from a xorg/Intel bug (specifically S-Video related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/763688). This cropped up when I upgraded from Maverick to Natty.

Is it possible and safe to install the old (Maverick) version of xserver-xorg-video-intel while keeping everything else? If so, how? (Preferably using a package rather than having to download and compile anything.) If it doesn't work, how do I revert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chatted to a colleague who gave me this answer. It is possible, but not advisable.

To install an alternate package:

- Open Synaptic Package Manager
- From the menu select Settings | Repositories
- Add the alternate source (in my case the maverick repo)
- You should be prompted to reload sources, if not hit the Reload button
- Find and select the package to downgrade
- From the menu select Package | Force version...
- Pick the older version
- You will be warned that this may cause dependency errors
- If you're feeling brave, go ahead

Reverting would involve undoing this process. In my case this involves dealing with a broken video driver, and that sounds like a nightmare, so I'll just wait for the bug to be fixed.